# get Table as xml - apache- poi

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

I create a Table  using apache poi like this:

```
 XWPFDocument document= new XWPFDocument();

      //Write the Document in file system
      FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("create_table.docx"));

      //create table
      XWPFTable table = document.createTable();

      //create first row
      XWPFTableRow tableRowOne = table.getRow(0);
      tableRowOne.getCell(0).setText("col one, row one");
      tableRowOne.addNewTableCell().setText("col two, row one");
      tableRowOne.addNewTableCell().setText("col three, row one");

      //create second row
      XWPFTableRow tableRowTwo = table.createRow();
      tableRowTwo.getCell(0).setText("col one, row two");
      tableRowTwo.getCell(1).setText("col two, row two");
      tableRowTwo.getCell(2).setText("col three, row two");

      //create third row
      XWPFTableRow tableRowThree = table.createRow();
      tableRowThree.getCell(0).setText("col one, row three");
      tableRowThree.getCell(1).setText("col two, row three");
      tableRowThree.getCell(2).setText("col three, row three");
```

Now I would like get table format and data in a String variable like:

```
<w:style w:type="table"...>
<w:rPr><w:t> data </w:t> </w:rPr>
```

Can I do this?

Comment: Not clear what kind of `XML` you mean. Office OpenXML of a Word table would be: `<w:tbl><w:tr><w:tc><w:p><w:r><w:t>cell text content</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc>...</w:tr>...</w:tbl>` where `tbl` is table, `tr` is table row, `tc` is table cell, `p` is paragraph, `r` is text run and `t` is text. So your sample `XML` is a little bit confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Office OpenXML of the [XWPFTable](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFTable.html) is meant, then:

[XWPFTable.getCTTbl()](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFTable.html#getCTTbl%28%29) returns a [CTTbl](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1/org/openxmlformats/schemas/wordprocessingml/x2006/main/CTTbl.java) and this extends [XmlObject](https://xmlbeans.apache.org/docs/2.6.0/reference/org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlObject.html) which provides a [XmlObject.toString()](https://xmlbeans.apache.org/docs/2.6.0/reference/org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlObject.html#toString%28%29) which returns an XML string for this XML object.

So

```
String tableXML = table.getCTTbl().toString();
```